# How to receive sensor's data in android app using WiFi connection?

Tags: android, wifi, iot, sensors

I have a motion detector sensor with WiFi, I'm able to connect to that WiFi with my android app.
But how to get the sensor's data into my app?

Comment: You have to find out what API the sensor exposes. You need documentation, or at least some reverse engineering.

Comment: I'm able to see the sensor's data on browser , just by entering the DNS of wifi device.
But what exactly i need to read that data in my app?

Comment: This is not the place for a complete course in RE, but basically, go to browser->developer tools->monitor network traffic. Visit the device in your browser. Examine the network traffic. Then, mimic the same calls using OkHttp/Volley. Parse the returned data.